# VBA - Calling module results in "expected variable procedure not module"

Tags: ms-access, vba

Right. So I have decided that when I move to splitting the FE/BE of my database I want to make use of '[Allen Brown's Error Handling in VBA](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-23a.html)' as this will allow the process to stop, inform user that action failed and log the error automatically for me to review at a later date.

Only problem is I keep getting the error "expected variable procedure not module"

Now I did adapt Allen's code slightly so instead of being called 'LogError' I've changed all that to 'LogAutoErrors'

This is the first sub that I have added the call code that is throwing the above error

```
Private Sub ImportAttendees_Click()
On Error GoTo ImportAttendees_Click_Err

Dim SelectedFile    As String
Dim FilePicker      As FileDialog
Dim SQLdelete       As String

Set FilePicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
FilePicker.AllowMultiSelect = False
FilePicker.Filters.Add "Excel", "*.xls*", 1
FilePicker.InitialFileName = "C:\Users\"
FilePicker.Title = "Select New Attendee List Location..."
FilePicker.Show

If FilePicker.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
    SelectedFile = FilePicker.SelectedItems(1)

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "tbl_STG_AttendeeImport", SelectedFile, True

    MsgBox prompt:="Data Staged - Ready For Import", buttons:=vbInformation, Title:="Data Loaded"
End If

Me.Refresh

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

ImportAttendees_Click_Err: ' Label to jump to on error.
MsgBox prompt:="E-Link encountered an error when processing the last action. E-Link has cancelled the last action and the error has been logged with the system administrator", buttons:=vbInformation, Title:="Database Process Error"
Call logAutoErrors(Err.Number, Err.Description, "ImportAttendees_Click()")
Resume Exit_ImportAttendees_Click
End Select
End Sub
```

The expected result is whenever I get errors (e.g. my favorite run-time error 3061) it inserts into the error table and cancels actions.

EDIT: Here is the amended Allen Browne code, only thing I changed was one field name and the module name

```
Function logAutoErrors(ByVal lngErrNumber As Long, ByVal strErrDescription As String, _
    strCallingProc As String, Optional vParameters, Optional bShowUser As Boolean = False) As Boolean
On Error GoTo Err_logAutoErrors
    ' Purpose: Generic error handler.
    ' Logs errors to table "tLogError".
    ' Arguments: lngErrNumber - value of Err.Number
    ' strErrDescription - value of Err.Description
    ' strCallingProc - name of sub|function that generated the error.
    ' vParameters - optional string: List of parameters to record.
    ' bShowUser - optional boolean: If False, suppresses display.
    ' Author: Allen Browne, allen@allenbrowne.com

    Dim strMsg As String      ' String for display in MsgBox
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset  ' The tLogError table

    Select Case lngErrNumber
    Case 0
        Debug.Print strCallingProc & " called error 0."
    Case 2501                ' Cancelled
        'Do nothing.
    Case 3314, 2101, 2115    ' Can't save.
        If bShowUser Then
            strMsg = "Record cannot be saved at this time." & vbCrLf & _
                "Complete the entry, or press <Esc> to undo."
            MsgBox strMsg, vbExclamation, strCallingProc
        End If
    Case Else
        If bShowUser Then
            strMsg = "Error " & lngErrNumber & ": " & strErrDescription
            MsgBox strMsg, vbExclamation, strCallingProc
        End If
        Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_ADM_ErrorLog", , dbAppendOnly)
        rst.AddNew
            rst![ErrNumber] = lngErrNumber
            rst![ErrDescription] = Left$(strErrDescription, 255)
            rst![ErrDate] = Now()
            rst![CallingProc] = strCallingProc
            rst![UserID] = TempVars!AUID
            If Not IsMissing(vParameters) Then
                rst![Parameters] = Left(vParameters, 255)
            End If
        rst.Update
        rst.Close
        LogError = True
    End Select

Exit_logAutoErrors:
    Set rst = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_logAutoErrors:
    strMsg = "An unexpected situation arose in your program." & vbCrLf & _
        "Please write down the following details:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Calling Proc: " & strCallingProc & vbCrLf & _
        "Error Number " & lngErrNumber & vbCrLf & strErrDescription & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Unable to record because Error " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    MsgBox strMsg, vbCritical, "logAutoErrors()"
    Resume Exit_logAutoErrors
End Function
```

Comment: Do you have a code module with the same name as the Sub you're calling?

Comment: I do not, it's the reason I named it 'AutoLogErrors' because I couldn't remember if LogError existed or was already defined in access

Comment: When you say `This is the first sub that I have added the call code that is throwing the above error`, do you mean this is the first attempt to add the code **_at all_**, or that you've successfully added it to other subs and this is the first one **_with errors_**?

Comment: Is the procedure "AutoLogErrors" or "LogAutoErrors". You reference the first in comment but the second in code.

Comment: Found line `Resume Exit_ImportAttendees_Click` but not label `Exit_ImportAttendees_Click`

Comment: to clarify it is 'logAutoErrors' - I'll need to rework the code because there is no 'Exit_ImportAttendees_Click' however just removing that line won't work lol

Comment: It looks like you are confusing modules with procedures. Procedures are: Functions or Subroutines. Modules are containers that hold Procedures. Can you tell us what the module name is? What object has this `Function logAutoErrors` code in it?

Comment: Yeah my bad, I store any 'reusable' function in their own module and usually name said module something similar to the function within. this case the module should have been 'ErrorLogging' but I derped and called the module logAutoErrors also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you have a Function or Sub that shares the same name as the Module. Every name must be unique. Even the Modules.

**EXAMPLE:**
[image]
***Notice the modules on the left. That is where your problem will be found.***

You had some strange things going on with your line labels. You also had an `End Select` with no select statement.

Try this:

```
Private Sub ImportAttendees_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim SelectedFile    As String
    Dim FilePicker      As FileDialog
    Dim SQLdelete       As String

    Set FilePicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With FilePicker
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Excel", "*.xls*", 1
        .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\"
        .Title = "Select New Attendee List Location..."
        .Show
    End With

    If FilePicker.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
        SelectedFile = FilePicker.SelectedItems(1)

        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "tbl_STG_AttendeeImport", SelectedFile, True

        MsgBox prompt:="Data Staged - Ready For Import", Buttons:=vbInformation, Title:="Data Loaded"
    End If

    Me.Refresh

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    MsgBox prompt:="E-Link encountered an error when processing the last action. E-Link has cancelled the last action and the error has been logged with the system administrator", Buttons:=vbInformation, Title:="Database Process Error"
    logAutoErrors Err.Number, Err.Description, "ImportAttendees_Click()"
    Resume
End Sub
```

Comment: well that is a lot cleaner... Still returns the complile error 'expected variable or procedure, not module'

Comment: On what line? That's the critical part that we need to help you. Otherwise we will just see all the other problems with the code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a label missing , 
you shoould put it in the right place

the label of

```
Resume Exit_ImportAttendees_Click
```

;

```
Private Sub ImportAttendees_Click()
On Error GoTo ImportAttendees_Click_Err

Dim SelectedFile    As String
Dim FilePicker      As FileDialog
Dim SQLdelete       As String

Set FilePicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
FilePicker.AllowMultiSelect = False
FilePicker.Filters.Add "Excel", "*.xls*", 1
FilePicker.InitialFileName = "C:\Users\"
FilePicker.Title = "Select New Attendee List Location..."
FilePicker.Show

If FilePicker.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
    SelectedFile = FilePicker.SelectedItems(1)

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "tbl_STG_AttendeeImport", SelectedFile, True

    MsgBox prompt:="Data Staged - Ready For Import", buttons:=vbInformation, Title:="Data Loaded"
End If
Exit_ImportAttendees_Click:
Me.Refresh

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

ImportAttendees_Click_Err: ' Label to jump to on error.
MsgBox prompt:="E-Link encountered an error when processing the last action. E-Link has cancelled the last action and the error has been logged with the system administrator", buttons:=vbInformation, Title:="Database Process Error"
Call logAutoErrors(Err.Number, Err.Description, "ImportAttendees_Click()")
Resume Exit_ImportAttendees_Click
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking at it. Although I was missing the label I've since added it however still get the same error